# (JavaScript) How to check JSON for key

Tags: javascript, sql, json, node.js

I have an endpoint for my API where it receives the body:

```
{
    "id" : 101,
    "value1" : 1,
    "value2" : 2,
    "value3" : 3
}
```

I then perform a query that updates the table with **value1**, **value2** and **value3** where id = **id**. However, I want to create something that checks if a ***key*** is present.

For example, I may only want to update **value2**, thus sending the following in the body:

```
{
    "id" : 101,
    "value2" : 2
}
```

I need my sql function to only perform:`"UPDATE table SET value2 = ?, WHERE id = ?";`

I would assume that the solution to this would be to have a for-loop to check for keys present in the object. If they are present create a variable, **data** which stores `value1 = a`, `value2 = b`, `value3, =c`?

Would this be the correct way, and if so how do I check if something is present in an object?

Comment: First of all, JSON is a string representation of an object, so do you have an object or JSON?  It's easier to work with an object, so if you do have JSON then using `JSON.parse(string)` will turn it into an object.  Then you just need a loop to parse the object keys - `Object.keys(yourObject).forEach(function(key) { yourObject[key].... });`

Comment: If you only want to update `value2`, send the updated value for `value2` along with the old values for `value1` and `value3`. This way you can use single SQL statement to update the object. It'll be messy to check and update only the fields present.

Comment: Apart from what archer mentioned, if you're still interested in just checking if particular thing exists in your object you can use objectName.hasOwnProperty(keyName);

Comment: @swdon would I not have to do a select statement, then an update if I want to go the initial values?

Comment: @N.Sainsbury to answer that, need to see more of your code. How you are doing the update. Usually, like Archer pointed out, before you update the database row, you would update the object. So, you would have the full object in hand.

Comment: @swdon The premise for this is that we have a database, with different 'relay times'. We have `r1on, r1off,...r8on,r8off`. These values control a PLC. However, there are situations where a user may only want to update `r2on` so will fill the form in and send `{ 'id' : 909, 'r2on' : 100}`. However, in the SQL statement, we need to know to only update `r2on`

Comment: Bind the form to a data model. That means when you load the form for `'id': 909`, you already have all the attributes of `909`. Then the user will change any attribute they like, in this case, `r2on`. Then send this whole updated object to the database for update. People use a design pattern called MVC to formalize this approach. If you are going to check, in code, which column to change and create SQL based on that, you might end up writing messy code.

Comment: @swdon so in summary, you would recommend SELECTING all the data first, then UPDATING everything?

Comment: Yes, select the row you want the user to update (not all the data).

Comment: @swdon OK. Sounds good, thanks for the help! I assume I would check the entry and put it into an object, check to see if the request of the body contains any of the same keys and then replace the key. Once that is done upload the new JSON to the database?

Comment: Yeah, it'll keep your code cleaner. Exact implementation depends on how the user updates the entry. If you are sure that the user can update only a key existing in the object, you don't need to explicitly check which key is being updated. You can do just do something like `Object[key_as_variable] = value`. Anyway, you got the idea right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the best way to do this is to use `hasOwnProperty`:

```js
const obj = {'a': 1, 'b': null};
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('a'));
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('b'));
console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('c'));
```

Comment: Thanks @Zevgon. Here's some code I wrote to test:
https://jsfiddle.net/w8xvm2mb/10/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check that JavaScript object key has any value or not:

```
if(obj['key'])
//If value present
else
//No value
```